# Math operations with value objects (VOs) using QueryDSL

Tags: querydsl

I am trying to take advantage of QueryDSL capabilities doing some operations while I'm still creating a List of certain DTO with information coming from my database, doing so I can avoid messy operations afterwards. The example below is a silly representation of what I am trying to achieve:

```
public class Product {
   private Quantity total;

   //more code here
}

public class Quantity {
   //code here
   public Quantity multiply(Quantity quantity) {
      return Quantity.of(this.value.multiply(quantity.numberValue());
   }
   //more code here
}



public static Function<JPQLQuery, List<MyDTO>> someMethod() {
   return q -> {

       //some code here

       q.from(...)

       //more code here

       .list(new QMyDTO(qProduct.total.multiply(qProduct.total).sum()));
   };
}
```

The problem is that QueryDSL uses a `NumberExpression` to provide some operations like sum, multiply etc., which works fine with types like `BigDecimal`, but doesn't work with custom types like my value object `Quantity`. I've tried to come up with something, but I had no success whatsoever and I didn't find anything like it out there.

Is there anything implemented that could help me achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a delegate method for this case

```
@QueryDelegate(Quantity.class)
public static Expression<Quantity> multiply(QQuantity quantity, Quantity other){
    return Expressions.operation(Quantity.class,
        Ops.MULTI, quantity, ConstantImpl.create(other));
}
```

After that you will be able express

```
qProduct.total.multiply(qProduct.total)
```

Comment: Thank you once again. I tried a delegate before, but without the Expressions part. That did the trick